# Error in deleting Ubuntu partition from Window

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, partitioning

I've got my machine on dual-boot. Now, I wish to delete the Ubuntu partition, as I need additional space on my Windows partition.

Problem is I'm unable to delete the partition. I get the following error:

[image: Delete partition Error]

I even tried using DiskPart but still

[image: Diskpart Error]

How can I resole this?

Comment: You can delete it from an Ubuntu Live Boot disc, using `Disks` or `gparted`, for example.

Comment: @AFH - So, right now if I boot my system from MBR and use gparted to clear that partition, I should not face any issues in booting into my Windows partition, right? Or is there anything else I need to be aware of?

Comment: You should look as Disc Management to make absolutely sure that you are trying to delete the correct partition. I can't be absolutely sure that there will be no other implications, so you must make a full drive back-up before you do any partition manipulation. A safer alternative might be to reformat the Ubuntu partition as NTFS, then mount it either as an auxiliary partition (eg `D:`), or as a mount point (such as `C:\Users`).